# Remove bottom shadow on bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, shadow, bootstrap-popover

How can I remove the bottom shadow on a bootstrap 3 popover?

[image]

I can't find the shadow anywhere in css, and I've removed all shadows from my css.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 300px
}
.teamMember {
 width: 60%;
 margin: auto;
 transition: all .3s ease;
 padding: 20px;
}

.teamMember:hover {
 box-shadow: 
  4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
  -4px -4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.teamMember img {
 width: 50%;
}

.teamMember h4 {
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: 'Arimo';
}

.teamMember h5 {
 text-transform: none !important;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.7) !important;
 font-size: 2em !important;
}

.popover {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('https://i.imgur.com/mmiTupu.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 text-shadow: none !important;
}

.popover-content {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 100px;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="teamMember" data-placement="top" data-content="oof<br/>test">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mmiTupu.jpg">
   <h4>oof</h4>
   <h5>oof</h5>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var template = [
 '<div class="popover">',
  '<div class="popover-content">',
  '</div>',
 '</div>'
 ].join('');
 $(".teamMember").popover({
  trigger: "hover",
  html: !0,
  template: template
 });
});
</script>
```

This snippet should produce the same error, but it's not for some reason, and I'm honestly so confused. There's no shadow I see in css or dev tools, so I'm a bit stuck. Since the snippet doesn't show the issue, here's it live: https://piggeh.org/meraki/team

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to remove that because its added on the background photo which is found in this url: https://piggeh.org/meraki/assets/images/team/popup.png

See here:

[image]

If you would want to keep that background without the shadow you should download and edit the photo in the url given above without the shadow and then re-upload it.